# Crashlytics request data for configuration

Tags: crashlytics, privacy, google-fabric, privacy-policy

is there any documentation about the initial configuration request to crashlytics servers on app start?

http://try.crashlytics.com/security/ only confirms the request, not giving any details. We need as much details about that request as possible for data-privacy reasons.

Furthermore, it's surprising that network connections to the following servers are opened, in order to execute that single request. Does anybody have explanations for that?

https://api.crashlytics.com

https://settings.crashlytics.com

https://ssl-download-crashlytics-com.s3.amazonaws.com

https://e.crashlytics.com

https://cm.crashlytics.com

https://reports.crashlytics.com

Answer (score 2):

Great question! There is no documentation on the settings call.

In that first call. We:

- Establish wether or not you have analytics turned on.
- Determine the current status of internal feature switches.
- Upload any remaining session details.
- Sometimes we upload the app icon.

Thanks!

```
Here is the full payload:

analytics =     {

    "flush_interval_secs" = 600;

    "flush_on_background" = 1;

    "max_byte_size_per_file" = 8000;

    "max_file_count_per_send" = 1;

    "max_pending_send_file_count" = 100;

    "track_view_controllers" = 0;

    url = "https://e.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/events";

};

app =     {

    identifier = "com.twitter.FabricSampleApp";

    "reports_url" = "https://reports.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/ios/apps/com.twitter.fabricsampleapp/reports";

    status = activated;

    "update_required" = 0;

    url = "https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v1/platforms/ios/apps/com.twitter.fabricsampleapp";

};

beta =     {

    "update_endpoint" = "https://api.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/com.twitter.FabricSampleApp/beta_update_check";

    "update_suspend_duration" = 3600;

};

"cache_duration" = 60;

features =     {

    "collect_analytics" = 0;

    "collect_logged_exceptions" = 1;

    "collect_reports" = 1;

    "prompt_enabled" = 0;

};

prompt =     {

    "always_send_button_title" = "Always Send";

    "cancel_button_title" = "Don't Send";

    message = "Looks like we crashed! Please help us fix the problem by sending a crash report.";

    "send_button_title" = Send;

    "show_always_send_button" = 1;

    "show_cancel_button" = 1;

    title = "Send Crash Report?";

};

session =     {

    "identifier_mask" = 255;

    "log_buffer_size" = 64000;

    "max_chained_exception_depth" = 16;

    "max_custom_exception_events" = 16;

    "max_custom_key_value_pairs" = 64;

};

"settings_version" = 2;
}
```